# How to remove the divergent part of loop integrals when employing the cuttoff procedure?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration, regularization

On page 130 of "A Modern Introduction to Quantum Field Theory" by Michele Maggiore they evaluate a divergent four dimensional integral writing:

> "We introduce a cuttoff stating that we integrate only over Euclidean momenta with $k^2 < \Lambda^2$, and we **extract the divergent part**."

My question is: how do they extract the divergent part of the integral? What is the systematic procedure that they employ to do this when using a cutoff?

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: If you only integrate up until some scale $\Lambda$ instead of infinity, you kind of 'extract' the divergent part, right? You can still send $\Lambda \to \infty$ and restore the original result, but you get to know the behaviour of divergence with this method.

Comment: Yeah, what was confusing me up was attempts to do these integrals in a cartesian coordinate system. If you switch to 4-sphere coordinates, and plug it into mathematica using a finite cutoff then it's obvious. What was missing from my books was that switch to 4-sphere coordinates. They instead just wrote down the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Extracting the divergent part only means that we keep the part that tends to infinity as one send the cut-off to infinity ($\Lambda\to\infty$).

For example, the typical tadpole integral in 4D reads
$$
\int_0^\Lambda dk \frac{k^3}{k^2+m^2}=\frac{\Lambda^2}{2}-\frac{m^2}{2}\log(\Lambda^2+m^2)+\frac{m^2}{2}\log(m^2)\\ \simeq \frac{\Lambda^2}{2}-\frac{m^2}{2}\log(\Lambda^2)+\frac{m^2}{2}\log(m^2)
$$
where the second line is obtained using the fact that the cut-off is larger than any other energy scale. Here, we see that the divergent part is  $\frac{\Lambda^2}{2}-\frac{m^2}{2}\log(\Lambda^2)$.

Comment: My apologies, I should be a little more clear about this. The night that I posted this I was actually looking at a tadpole graph that gives something like what you have on page 131 of Maggiore, but just like in your example (which I appreciate), they didn't explicitly evaluate the integral starting from it's original d^4 k form which had lead me to some confusion... (continued in next comment)

Comment: In fact, I haven't yet been able to find a source that clearly and explicitly evaluates these integrals (which is how I ended up here) so I guessed by first substituting in the Euclidean momentum: k^2= (k_0)^2 + (k_i) into the integral, integrating over k_0, and then integrating over each k_i momentum one at a time in Mathematica. My initial calculation was flawed, but if I do it right, the first integral (without using the volume element sub) looks like: Normal[Integrate[1/((l^2 + p^2 + m^2)), {l, a, b}]] where l = k_0. Which gives me some arctan functions... (continued in next comment)

Comment: However, mathematica won' t evaluate the next integral (I suppose 
this means that it can' t be expressed in algebraic terms) which lead 
me deeper into my doubts.I had suspected that they had either used 
some kind of bizarre method or a 4 D volume element which for some 
math reason does not have this issue.... (continued in next comment)

Comment: It looks like you' ve opted to use the 4 D volume element.My dilemma was that I couldn' t simply accept this as correct because I haven' t yet seen or thought of a proof that shows that d^4 k = (constant) r^3 dr is applicable to a complex 4D Euclidean space, although I imagine that said proof is probably obvious, and intuitive, I' ll have to go look into it for the sake of clarity. I'll probably be able to see why we can get away with this by just looking at the wikipedia page for the n-sphere. Thanks for the response Adam.

Comment: I think you just need to go through this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates